# Pressione "Guia" para pesquisar no site?

Tags: google-chrome

Recentemente eu fui acessar o site do [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) pelo Google Chrome e me deparei com um recurso interessante que é o ["Tab to Search" (Omnibox)](https://www.chromium.org/tab-to-search).

Em resumo, ao digitar o endereço de um site e apertar a tecla <kbd>Tab</kbd> você realiza a busca diretamente em um site específico sem a necessidade de alterar o mecanismo de busca e outras soluções.

A imagem abaixo ilustra melhor o que estou dizendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seguindo exemplo do [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), ao pressionar <kbd>Tab</kbd> e realizar uma busca, o browser me redireciona para a página de busca do site, nesse caso **https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=termo%20pesquisado**.

Diante disse, tenho três perguntas que estão interligadas, que são:

- Qual recurso é esse?
- Como adicionar ao meu site?
- Somente o Google Chrome possui esse suporte?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630144/how-to-add-google-chrome-omnibox-search-support-for-your-site

Comment: @durtto Obrigado pelo link. Já li ele e outros. Queria apenas trazer para cá pois não encontrei nada parecido aqui. xD

Comment: Quanto tempo já existe isso? Vi isso pela primeira vez hoje!!! Que loucura!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente se refere ao [`application/opensearchdescription+xml`](http://www.opensearch.org/Home), é um formato de XML que adiciona busca personalizada para o seu site, deve ficar algo assim:

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Titulo" href="busca.xml">
```

E o busca.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"
                   xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
    <ShortName>Nome do buscador</ShortName>
    <Description>Descrição</Description>
    <Tags>asp.net programar core</Tags>
    <Contact>email de contato</Contact>
    <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding> <!-- altere para o seu charset padrão usado na página nos inputs -->
    <OutputEncoding>UTF-8</OutputEncoding> <!-- altere para o seu charset padrão usado na página na saida -->
    <Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">{endereço do icone}</Image>

    <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://www.meusite.com.br/busca?q={searchTerms}" />
    <Url type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"
        rel="self"
        template="http://www.meusite.com.br/busca.xml" />
    <Language>pt-BR</Language> <!-- idioma da página -->
    <AdultContent>false</AdultContent>
    <Attribution>Atribuição do proprietário/empresa</Attribution>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

> A maior parte das tags é opcional, vou pesquisar um pouco mais e adicionar o detalhamento sobre cada uma, tem mais configurações possíveis porém faz algum tempo que não trabalho com isto.

Note que cada página dentro de um mesmo site pode ter o seu próprio XML de pesquisa.

Para ajustar o envio da requisição ajuste o metodo, sendo POST ou GET com o atributo `method=""` e o `template=` contendo a url, o `{searchTerms}` será obtido pelo que o usuário editou, isto tudo deve ser feito na tag `Url`:

```
<Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://www.meusite.com.br/busca?q={searchTerms}"></Url>
```

### Lista de sugestões pré-definidas:

É possível usar a tag com a URL de um json com sugestões pré-definidas:

```
 <Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" template="URL do json" />
```

Exemplo:

```
[
   "sea",
   [
      "sears",
      "search engines",
      "search engine",
      "search",
      "sears.com",
      "seattle times"
   ],
   [
      "7,390,000 results",
      "17,900,000 results",
      "25,700,000 results",
      "1,220,000,000 results",
      "1 result",
      "17,600,000 results"
   ],
   [
      "http://meusite.com.br?q=sears",
      "http://meusite.com.br?q=search+engines",
      "http://meusite.com.br?q=search+engine",
      "http://meusite.com.br?q=search",
      "http://meusite.com.br?q=sears.com",
      "http://meusite.com.br?q=seattle+times"
   ]
]
```

O formato do array:

- No primeiro item do array temos a palavra que irá buscar as sugestões
- No segundo temos 6 sugestões de palavas
- No terceiro temos o resultado para cada sugestão
- No quarto temos as urls que podem ser modificadas para cada palavra, podendo facilitar o uso com urls amigáveis.

### Suporte:

Navegadores como Google Chrome e Firefox suportam bem o `opensearchdescription`, mas outros navegadores não tem tanto ou nenhum suporte para isto, de qualquer forma deixar o `<link type="search" ...>` não vai afeta-los negativamente.

Comment: Mas no Firefox existe alguma opção para buscar direto no site sem precisar alternar o "Mecanismo de Busca"?

Comment: @Randrade o Firefox tentou implementar a propria versão do Omibox, mas removeram (lembro-me de ter usado), hoje eles funcionam semelhante, mas não em todos aspectos, no caso do opensearch somente clicano no sinal de "mais" no buscador e adicionando. É algo proprio do navegador, somente o Chrome e alguns outros baseados no chrome fazem toda interação com algo semelhante ao Omibox, é uma característica do navegador (admito que acho bem mais prático, a Google entende dos UX :D)

Comment: A Google sendo a Google. kkk